# Github pull request to a deleted branch

Tags: git, github

I'm not sure how this would play out in Github and I don't want to mess up things so I wonder if you can answer this.

I have the following branches in my repo:

```
master
|
|
|
*   
|\  branch A - New branch for bigger framework changes
| |
| |
| |
| *
| |
| |
| |
| *   
| |\  branch B - New feature branch depending on the bigger framework changes
| | | 
| | |
| | |
| | * 
| | |
```

I'm done with the work with both `Branch A` and `B`, they are pushed to Github. I created a pull request of `Branch A` (compared to master). I'm about to create another pull request of `Branch B` compared to `Branch A` to get my changes revised. What happens if `Branch A` gets merged to master and the branch is deleted? Will I be able to merge `Branch B` **from the original pull request** or I'll need to open a new one comparing `Branch B` to the master?

```
| | | 
| | |
| | |
| | * 
| | |
| | |
| | |
|/  |
*   |
|   /
|  /
| /
|/
*
|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` is getting merged into `master` before `B`, then you should open the pull request from branch `B` to master. Otherwise you can request `B` be merged into `A` and then both into `master`.

Github just recently added support for showing 'deleted' branches, but I wouldn't count on it for a proper workflow.

Comment: I see. The reason I don't open a pull request for `B..master` is that it will show the changes of `A`. I guess the best is to wait until `A` is merged and then open a PR for `B`. Still, I'm curious what would happen to PR `A..B` if I deleted `A`

Comment: @gphilip - if I understand the recent changes correctly, you'll still see a proper diff.